# OpenFL responsive interface design

Tags: user-interface, haxe, openfl

Do anyone knows here, how to design the OpenFL game interfaces that are responsive so that it automatically adjusts on mobiles and tablets?

Comment: There is probably someone here that knows it. Jokes aside, you need to be a lot more specific. Where are you running into troubles? What and how have you tried to solve?

Answer (score 1):

You could look at [Not-so-simple SWF Layout](http://player03.com/2015/04/05/not-so-simple-swf-layout/) post and [Advanced Layout](https://github.com/player-03/advanced-layout) library